# Change jQuery function in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this jQuery function in ASP.NET MVC project

```
        $(document).on("click", "a.grid-activate-user", function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                var page = $("#usersGrid").data("page");
                $.post("@Url.Action("Unlock", "AdminUsers")", { id: id }, function (result) {
                    if (!result.Succeeded) {
                        toastr.error(result.Message, "Error", { positionClass: "toast-top-right" });
                    } else {
                        toastr.success(result.Message, "Info", { positionClass: "toast-bottom-right" });
                    }
                    loadGrid(page);
                });
            });
```

and I need to add here checking if one property from model which I use `Model.ActionsAllowed == true`.
If `Model.ActionsAllowed == true` I need to execute this click-function, in other case I need to do nothing, but I don't know how to add this checking in the function.

**UPD** If I try use

```
$(document).on("click", "a.grid-activate-user", function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var page = $("#usersGrid").data("page");
            if (Model.ActionsAllowed) {
                $.post("@Url.Action("Unlock", "AdminUsers")", { id: id }, function (result) {
                    if (!result.Succeeded) {
                        toastr.error(result.Message, "Error", { positionClass: "toast-top-right" });
                    } else {
                        toastr.success(result.Message, "Info", { positionClass: "toast-bottom-right" });
                    }
                    loadGrid(page);
                });
            };
        });
```

it works, but I get *Use of implicity declared global variable 'Model'*. How to fix it?

Comment: Put the value of Model.ActionsAllowed in an JS variable and use the variable in the if-function. Something like: var allowed = @Model.ActionsAllowed.ToString().ToLower();

Comment: I get the same warning because I again use Model inside my script.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this it put the value for `Model.ActionsAllowed == true` in a hidden field and refer to that in your JS

e.g. in your view

```
@Html.Hidden("hid-actions-allowed", Model.ActionsAllowed)
```

And then in your JS

```
$(document).on("click", "a.grid-activate-user", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var page = $("#usersGrid").data("page");
    if ($('#hid-actions-allowed').val()) {
        $.post("@Url.Action("Unlock", "AdminUsers")", { id: id }, function (result) {
            if (!result.Succeeded) {
                toastr.error(result.Message, "Error", { positionClass: "toast-top-right" });
            } else {
            toastr.success(result.Message, "Info", { positionClass: "toast-bottom-right" });
            }
            loadGrid(page);
        });
    };
});
```